# XML parsing error: <unknown>:26:41: mismatched tag

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, validation, feed

this is a wordpress installation. I have tried everything I can think of. It says the code is malformed. I even tried adding the   tag to the feed-rss2.php

For some reason no matter what changes I make it does not matter. i know this is the right file because if I delete things the site gets weird

here is the raw code in the area where the validator says its not correct

```
<dc:creator><![CDATA[<?php the_author() ?></dc:creator>
    <![CDATA[<?php the_category_rss() ?>
```

You can clearly see right here that the category is not being opened and closed

here is the link to the validation of that php

[Feed Validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2F1fungrltravels.com%2Ffeed)

Comment: Full xml output is at [link](http://www.1fungrltravels.com/feed)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're defining this data...but you need to close your brackets:

```
<dc:creator><![CDATA[<?php the_author(); ?>]]></dc:creator>
                                           ^^^
```

Comment: I tried that and it still will not validate!  In the editor it shows improper syntax

Comment: Does it show the error on the same line when you make that change?

Comment: it does and also shows "unexpected text" now as well

Comment: Any other thoughts, I returned it to its default save version until something else can be tried!